# Unable to run a test function when it contains another service function

Tags: typescript, undefined, ts-jest

Getting this error when running the test cases written in Jest. (Typescript)

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update')
```

Here is my fuction:

```
it('calling refresh method', () => {
      refreshController.update(obj1, obj2);
      expect(otherService.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
obj1,
    obj2,
      );
    });
```

What could be the possible reason?

I am expecting it to not to throw error.
I tried using async await as well, and on consoling the `this` object, I got an empty object.